# Am not getting sensor data values in android emulator

Tags: android

After connecting sensor simulator to android emulator, after giving that IP address from sensor simulator in android emulator,then after choosing testing button, also after pressing connect button, am not getting that sensor data values. I was waiting after clicking that connect button for long time. Am not getting that sensor data values in android

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but it seems that setting sensor values in the emulator using commands via telnet is broken when using some versions of Android.

When I run Android 2.2 in an emulator, and connect with telnet and then give a command such as `sensor set acceleration 1:2:3`, it works as expected, but with Android 2.3.3 in the emulator the command has no effect. (I have not tried newer versions.)

Answer (score 0):

I have used telnet sensor accelerator 1:2:3 with the emulator at the 4.4.2 level.  I am running on Windows 7 x64.  I find that it works, however if I backspace to correct an misspelling or change a value it fails.
My application running on the emulator does receive and process all accepted entries.